# Monitor source control Jenkins without checkout of the source control

Tags: mercurial, jenkins

How would one make a job in Jenkins that polls source 
control (i.e. mercurial) as a triggers it to execute the job, but
without actually clone/pull the monitored repo?

Answer (score 0):

If it already has a local clone and you just don't want to update it can run `hg incoming` whose exit code lets you know if there's new stuff.  If you don't have a local clone you'll need to run something like `hgweb` on the box that's serving the repo and then poll the raw version of the latest commit and watch for changes: http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/raw-rev/tip